# What is the "__gmon_start__" symbol?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, elf, binutils

I'm compiling this code with `gcc hello.c -o hello -O3`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and when I list the relocations I get:

```
test@southpark$ readelf -r hello | grep gmon
080495a4  00000106 R_386_GLOB_DAT    00000000   __gmon_start__
080495b4  00000107 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   __gmon_start__
```

When I list the symbols in this file I get:

```
test@southpark$ readelf -s hello | grep gmon
     1: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
    48: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
```

Does `gmon_start` have anything to do with gprof? Why does it have a relocation for that symbol even I didn't compile/link with `-pg` or `-g`? What library would resolve this symbol?

Answer (score 18):

Did a little googling and found this from [here](http://www.mentalcases.net/texts/security/TextSectionStudy.txt):

> The function call_gmon_start initializes the gmon profiling system.
>   This system is enabled when binaries are compiled with the -pg flag,
>   and creates output for use with gprof(1). In the case of the scenario
>   binary call_gmon_start is situated directly proceeding that _start
>   function. The call_gmon_start function finds the last entry in the
>   Global Offset Table (also known as __gmon_start__) and, if not NULL,
>   will pass control to the specified address. The __gmon_start__ element
>   points to the gmon initialization function, which starts the recording
>   of profiling information and registers a cleanup function with
>   atexit(). In our case however gmon is not in use, and as such
>   __gmon_start__ is NULL.

**So...**

1. Yes, it does have something to do with gprof
2. I'm not sure why the symbol is getting left in there. Maybe just a place holder for when it's compiled for gprof?

***Update:***

Okay, so I compiled your code with and without `-pg`. It looks like `__gmon_start__` gets mapped to an address within the compiled program. So with that being said, I don't think there's a library which resolves that symbol, but the program itself.

**with `-pg`:**

```
akyserr@orion:~$ readelf -r hello

Relocation section '.rel.dyn' at offset 0x32c contains 1 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
08049fec  00000806 R_386_GLOB_DAT    08048460   __gmon_start__

Relocation section '.rel.plt' at offset 0x334 contains 6 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
0804a000  00000607 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   080483b0   _mcleanup
0804a004  00000107 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   __monstartup
0804a008  00000207 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   mcount
0804a00c  00000307 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   __cxa_atexit
0804a010  00000407 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   puts
0804a014  00000507 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   __libc_start_main
```

**objdump of __gmon_start__ code:**

```
akyserr@orion:~$ objdump -S hello  | grep "460 <__gmon_start__>:" -A 20

08048460 <__gmon_start__>:
 8048460:       83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
 8048463:       a1 20 a0 04 08          mov    0x804a020,%eax
 8048468:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 804846a:       75 2a                   jne    8048496 <__gmon_start__+0x36>
 804846c:       c7 05 20 a0 04 08 01    movl   $0x1,0x804a020
 8048473:       00 00 00 
 8048476:       c7 44 24 04 36 86 04    movl   $0x8048636,0x4(%esp)
 804847d:       08 
 804847e:       c7 04 24 30 84 04 08    movl   $0x8048430,(%esp)
 8048485:       e8 36 ff ff ff          call   80483c0 <__monstartup@plt>
 804848a:       c7 04 24 b0 83 04 08    movl   $0x80483b0,(%esp)
 8048491:       e8 1a 01 00 00          call   80485b0 <atexit>
 8048496:       83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
 8048499:       c3                      ret    
 804849a:       90                      nop
 804849b:       90                      nop
 804849c:       90                      nop
 804849d:       90                      nop
```

With the `__gmon_start__` present in the compiled `hello` program, you can see that that `__monstartup` is called into. ([monstartup man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/monstartup/))

**without `-pg`:**

```
akyserr@orion:~$ readelf -r hello 

Relocation section '.rel.dyn' at offset 0x290 contains 1 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
08049ff0  00000206 R_386_GLOB_DAT    00000000   __gmon_start__

Relocation section '.rel.plt' at offset 0x298 contains 3 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
0804a000  00000107 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   puts
0804a004  00000207 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   __gmon_start__
0804a008  00000307 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   __libc_start_main
```

You can see here, that the symbol value of `__gmon_start__` is set to `00000000`.

Comment: about about the third question? Should I consider the last entry in GOT as the address of __gmon_start__ ? Also, inspecting the binary of "hello" it turns out that there is an entry: __gmon_start__@plt and another (the PLT entry) __gmon_start__@plt-0x10>

Comment: So how does the offset for `gmon_start` get mapped to a physical address?