# Getting in-process backtraces in a static linked binary

Tags: c++, c, stack-trace, backtrace

Glibc provides `backtrace()` and `backtrace_symbols()` for accessing a stack trace from within a process, independent of debugging symbols. However, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623884/gcc-debug-symbols-g-flag-vs-linkers-rdynamic-option), a statically linked binary will omit the necessary `.dynsym` section even if the flag `-rdynamic` has been passed.

I'm aware of methods based on debugging symbols, using `libdwarf` or `libdw` from ELF utils. For reasons of binary size (and associated compilation time) and licensing (for the particular mentioned libraries), I'd prefer not to rely on those.

Comment: It looks like `libunwind` depends on the same dynamic symbol table for naming: https://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/man/unw_get_proc_name(3).html

Comment: Did you try using `--export-dynamic`?

Comment: That's exactly what passing `-rdynamic` to the compiler driver will cause it to pass to the linker. Unless you're suggesting that the linker will do what I want if I pass it explicitly, while the compiler driver suppresses it when calling the linker for a static binary? I.e. Are you suggestion I try `-Wl,-export-dynamic` instead of `-rdynamic`?

Comment: libunwind works in statically linked executables.

Comment: Does it provide symbolic names, or just addresses? If it's providing symbol names, where is it getting them from that glibc `backtrace()` isn't?

Comment: It provides names, try it.